# Change position of div media-container with css

Tags: css, stylus

I can not change position of this video and it's driving me insane :)
I am using Firefox and Stylus (to write custom css for webpages).

On this website (https://sportsport.ba/fudbal/rabona-zahavija-u-90-minuti-za-pobjedu/333293) there is `media-container`

If I change bottom to auto I can see full video (see pictures below)
How can I save this change (`bottom:auto;`) to style? I've tried:

```
.media-container {
  bottom:auto;
}

div.media-container {
  bottom:auto;
}

div.media-container.media-container {
  bottom:auto;
}
```

and many more combinations but can't find the right one

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzEGN.jpg)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NKJP.jpg)

Comment: have you tried to use important .media-container {
  bottom:auto!important;
}

Comment: yes, I've tried it (no difference)

Comment: have you tried margin:0;

Comment: yes and it works when I edit inside dev tools (F12), but I can not find the correct code for making it permanent with stylus

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you :)

```
div.media-container{ 
    height:100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't seem to make any difference (if I check code on webpage (F12), there is no change)

If I change height to 100% with F12, video aspect is not correct (position is still wrong)

Comment: You must use ``` height:100% !important;``` for see the difference. Or i misunderstood you because of my English :)